# 10W LED flickering - what's the correct connection?

Tags: led, capacitor, resistors

Sorry for the stupid question, but what's the proper way to connect this LED? Do I need to add some resistor or capacitor? If I connect it directly to 12V, it works fine, but sometimes it "flickers" for some time. How do I stop it?

[image: 10W LED]

Comment: What does the datasheet for the LED indicate? You do have a datasheet for it, right?

Comment: Connecting it directly to 12V is probably not the correct way.

Comment: That does not look like a 12V constant voltage LED.  Are you regulating current somehow or just letting it burn with as much current as the supply can source?

Comment: https://components101.com/diodes/1-watt-led

Comment: You need CCS: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=1w+led+CCS+

Comment: We don't know what LED that is so we don't know what is the correct connection to it and to what kind of supply. We also don't know to what supply and how are you connecting it currently so we can't know why it flickers. You might want to add some details.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search tells me its a 12V LED Array rated at 10W or 1.2A (similar to one I got 15 yrs ago)

This requires a CPU type heatsink to keep cool or a smaller one with fan using thermal grease and the proper torque rating just like mounting a CPU chip.

Otherwise, it overheats then the NTC effects reduce the diode voltage which on a 12V supply means it starts to draw massively more current and then the supply senses over current,so it flashes off then tries again and repeats.

Without knowing what you have, **ensure your supply is 12.0V and rated for more than  1A minimum with a little old CPU heatsink and 12V fan.**  old CPU power supplies are a good salvage item.

Also do not stare at the LED up close. It's bad for your eyes.

If you do not have a 12V supply and want to run it on a car then you must regulate down to 12V or drop2.2V with 3 power diodes from 14.2 or use what is called a current limiter for 10W/12V=825mA